# ¿Cómo extraigo una cadena de texto dentro de un texto en Excel?

Tags: excel, string, split

¿Cómo extraigo una cadena de texto dentro de un texto en Excel?

Tengo los siguientes datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi objetivo es poder extraer las palabras entre asteriscos y después sustituirlas por: "_____". Para que me de un resultado así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con =ENCONTRAR para que me de la posición de el primer asterisco y después la misma función para el segundo y así poder atraparla con =EXTRAER, pero siento que es poco practico.
Un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hay una pregunta similar a la tuya en este post (está en ingles):
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/34821589/13355700](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34821589/13355700) Mira a ver si con esto consigues adaptar tu formula.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la función `SUSTITUIR`, en tu caso podrías anidar 3 veces la fórmula para obtener el resultado que necesitas, algo así:

```
=SUSTITUIR(SUSTITUIR(SUSTITUIR(A1;"*sehen*";"______");"*aus*";"______");"*sieht*";"______")
```

*La función `SUSTITUIR` te pide un parámetro que es la veces en las que se repite la palabra a sustituir, si omites ese parámetro como yo hice las sustituirá todas las veces que aparezca.

Este sería el resultado:

[image: resultado]